# BufferedImage Rotation

Tags: java, image-manipulation

What is the best way of rotating a bufferedimage about its center where the gradient is 1 degree?

I know there is AffineTransform, but that causes shearing and weird stretching or black spots that should be blank.

*edit* The sizes of images I am dealing with are icon sizes, so typically 24x24 up to 48x48 pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quality of rotation for such a small angle will vary greatly with the size of the image. How big is your image?

[After the OP edited the question to indicate the size of the image]

IMO the image is too small for any meaningful rotation other than in multiples of 90 degrees (assuming its a square). I am afraid this needs to be done manually by a graphic designer to get the best possible quality.

[Another alternative]

Keep a high res version of the image around. Apply all your transformations to this image and then scale down to obtain an icon.

Comment: generally between 24x24 pixels to 48x48 pixels, it is a very small image

Comment: yeah, anything this small even a 1 degree change is never 1 degree.  its either 0 or 45, isn't it?  a pixel either moves or it doesn't.

Comment: Huh? Of course it's possible to rotate a small image, it just means that some pixels will move while some won't. Consider a line going from (0,0) to (639,0) compared to one going from (0,0) to (639,1), and so on.

Comment: 639? I hope those are not pixels! If they are then I think you missed the point.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the anti-aliasing of your graphics context?

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty fix, have you considered the following method:

- scale up the image by a factor of eg 8, by drawing it onto a new bufferedimage
- rotate the image, by drawing it transformed by an affinetransform
- scale it back down again, by drawing it onto yet another new bufferedimage

Any low-level artefacts should vanish during the scale-down. This isn't perhaps the fastest option, but it may well do what you want with a minimum of fuss - and more complex solutions may likely boil down to doing the same thing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links which explain how you might want to proceed when applying transforms to icons.

**Java 2D Trickery: Antialiased Image Transforms**
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/campbell/archive/2007/03/java_2d_tricker_1.html

**Sub pixel sampling of Raster or DataBuffer in BufferedImage.** 
http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=204921&tstart=0